# Open data sets about software development: code quality, defect rate, programming languages?

Tags: data-request, software

I'm looking for open freely available data sets related to software development quality: code quality, defect rates, comparison across programming languages. Where/how can I find such data sets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few sources to take a look through:

- Most comprehensive and closest to what I think you're looking for is a project by the acronym of [PROMISE (PRedictOr Models In Software Engineering)](https://code.google.com/p/promisedata/). Go to http://promisedata.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/defect/ to go straight to their data which is organized by code base and into CSVs. For example, [tomcat.csv](http://promisedata.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/defect/tomcat/tomcat.csv). It looks like the project also has a number of tools to help analyze and create models from the data.
- [Eclipse Bug Data!](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/softevo/bug-data/eclipse/) is, as it sounds, a project to mine bug and version datas from the Eclipse project.
- NASA also publishes "cleaned versions of publicly available NASA MDP software defects data sets" over at http://nasa-softwaredefectdatasets.wikispaces.com/

*EDIT*: there are also a number of academic papers on this topic that you might want to skim to see if they reference specific data sets or sources.

Answer (score 3):

Note: This answer only covers a particular aspect of code quality.

[OpenHub](https://www.openhub.net) (ex Ohloh) contains 666,192 projects and mentions for each one:

- The number of comment lines
- The total number of lines
- The programming language used (or proportions if several used)

So, you can use that data to compute the comment/code ratio for many programming languages.

License: CC-BY

Answer (score 1):

Some of the projects listed under the data sets section of [dspinelli's awesome list](https://github.com/dspinellis/awesome-msr#data-sets) for mining software repositories (MSR) stuff might be useful.  Some examples (additional information found on the [GitHub list](https://github.com/dspinellis/awesome-msr) and through the links themselves):

- [CoREBench: Realisitic, complex regression errors](https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~release/corebench/)
- [Bug Prediction dataset](http://bug.inf.usi.ch/index.php)
- [Unified Bug Dataset](http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~ferenc/papers/UnifiedBugDataSet/)
- [Ultimate Debian Database](https://wiki.debian.org/UltimateDebianDatabase)
- [RepoReapers](https://reporeapers.github.io/results/1.html)
- [Maven Metrics](https://github.com/bkarak/data_msr2015)